# Received unregistered task of type in celery beat

Tags: django, django-celery, celerybeat

I can't seem to find what's missing.

In the ecommerce app I have a jobs folder with `__init__.py` and `order.py` files.
Here's `order.py`

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def test():
    print("Test completed")
```

These are from `settings.py`.

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'order_data_synchronization': {
        'task': 'ecommerce.jobs.order.test',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
    },
}
```

In 3 tabs I run `python3 manage.py runserver`, `redis-server` and `celery -A my-project.celery worker --loglevel=info --beat`

Every 5 seconds the following message appears with large logs

```
Received unregistered task of type 'ecommerce.jobs.order.test'.
```